# Handling overwriting of unique Dictionary values

Tags: c#, datetime, comparative-review, hash-map

I am working in C# to write a scheduling application for operations in a factory. I have a custom class `Workday`, with properties to represent a `Workday` for the operations in the shop. I also have a class `Timeline` that contains a dictionary of `DateTime`s as keys (using `DateTime.Date` to make sure we don't have two `Workday`s on the same date) and a `Workday` with the same `Date` as `Key.Date` as the value. When writing getters/setters for the `Dictionary` in the `Timeline` class, is it better to allow for overwriting a `Workday`, or is it preferred to clear the properties of the `Workday` and repopulate those values with new data?

```
public class Workday
{
    private Dictionary<ShopOperation, List<BOMProject>> OperationProjectPairs = new Dictionary<ShopOperation, List<BOMProject>>();
    public DateTime DayStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DayEnd { get; set; }

    public void SetProjects(ShopOperation key, List<BOMProject> value)
    {
        if (OperationProjectPairs.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            OperationProjectPairs[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            OperationProjectPairs.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public List<BOMProject> GetProjects(ShopOperation key)
    {
        List<BOMProject> result = null;

        if (OperationProjectPairs.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            result = OperationProjectPairs[key];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

`Timeline` with getter that allows for full overwrite:

```
public class Timeline
{
    private Dictionary<DateTime, Workday> ScheduledDays = new Dictionary<DateTime, Workday>();

    public Workday GetWorkday( DateTime date )
    {
        Workday result = null;

        foreach( KeyValuePair<DateTime, Workday> pair in ScheduledDays)
        {
            if( pair.Key.Date == date.Date)
            {
                result = pair.Value;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void SetWorkday( DateTime key, Workday value)
    {
        bool scheduled = false;

        foreach( KeyValuePair<DateTime, Workday> pair in ScheduledDays)
        {
            if( pair.Key.Date == value.DayStart.Date)
            {
                ScheduledDays[key] = value;
                scheduled = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!scheduled)
        {
            ScheduledDays.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

`Timeline` that will throw an exception if you try to overwrite a `Workday`:

```
public class Timeline
{
    private Dictionary<DateTime, Workday> ScheduledDays = new Dictionary<DateTime, Workday>();

    public Workday GetWorkday( DateTime date )
    {
        Workday result = null;

        foreach( KeyValuePair<DateTime, Workday> pair in ScheduledDays)
        {
            if( pair.Key.Date == date.Date)
            {
                result = pair.Value;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void SetWorkday( DateTime key, Workday value) Throws WorkdayOverwriteException
    {
        foreach( KeyValuePair<DateTime, Workday> pair in ScheduledDays)
        {
            if( pair.Key.Date == value.DayStart.Date)
            {
                throw new WorkdayOverwriteException();
            }
        }

        ScheduledDays.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RubberDuck, I don't know how to make individual works look like Code :D

Comment: No problem! You use backticks. You might want to check out the [formatting guide in the help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [this one on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/check-list-for-formatting-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your question is concerned, I'm not sure either choice is *best*, but if you had to choose one or the other, I would let them overwrite an existing one.

Consider that right now the user has no way to override a workday with a new one directly, so they would have to call `GetWorkday` to get a reference to it, and then change the properties of that object.

I think the best option would be to provide an overload that takes a `Boolean` that allows the user to determine if they want to overwrite a value:

```
public void SetWorkday( Workday value, bool overwrite)
```

Also, you haven't provided them with any way to `RemoveWorkday`, which might be a helpful addition.

---

For code reviewing thoughts, what are the fields `DayStart` and `DayEnd` for? I thought a workday was just a single day? Seems like it should just have a `Date` field.

---

In your get workday method, you could add a `break;` when you find the day you're looking for (since you don't need to keep searching):

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<DateTime, Workday> pair in ScheduledDays)
{
    if( pair.Key.Date == date.Date)
    {
        result = pair.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

In your `SetWorkday` method, I think you only need to pass in a `Workday` object, not a `DateTime key`. The reason is that a `Workday` already has a `DateTime` associated with it, and looking at your code, it seems like it's an easy entry point for a bug where someone passes in a `key` whose date is different than `Workday.DayStart`:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<DateTime, Workday> pair in ScheduledDays)
{
    if( pair.Key.Date == value.DayStart.Date)  // <- Comparing the workday date value
    {
        ScheduledDays[key] = value;            // <- But setting it using the key value
        scheduled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, in a few places you are checking if a key exists, and if it does you use assign the value using the index, but if it doesn't then you call the `Add` method. This is unnecessary - you can use the index assignment syntax for both. This will simplify your code. Here are 3 examples of different options and the simplified syntax:

```
// Overwrites
public void SetWorkday(Workday value)
{
    ScheduledDays[value.DayStart.Date] = value;
}

// Allows Overwriting
public void SetWorkday(Workday value, bool overwrite)
{
    if (ScheduleDays.ContainsKey(value.DayStart.Date) && !overwrite)
    {
        throw new WorkdayOverwriteException();
    }

    ScheduledDays[value.DayStart.Date] = value;
}

// Does not allow overwriting
public void SetWorkday(Workday value)
{
    if (ScheduleDays.ContainsKey(value.DayStart.Date))
    {
        throw new WorkdayOverwriteException();
    }

    ScheduledDays[value.DayStart.Date] = value;
}
```

Comment: I added a RemoveWorkday() function that allows the user to remove a Workday on a given date. DayStart and DayEnd are DateTimes that refer to the time of the day that the shift will start. (They are on the same Date, but with different times) Thanks for the answer! It was very helpful!